# How to copy-paste a file that already exists?

Tags: c#, file

I use this simple line of code to copy-paste a file:

```
File.Copy(filename, temp_file);
```

Now if a file already exists, I want to rename it prior to copying into some name that is guaranteed not to exist in destination folder by adding some name extension like 'copy1' 'copy2'....same as windows does it when doing copy-paste through explorer. How to do this programatically?

Comment: Do you want to rename the existing file or the new one?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Something like that:

```
    private static void MoveCopy(String source, String target) {
      // assuming that target directory exists

      if (!File.Exists(target))
        File.Copy(source, target);
      else
        for (int i = 1; ; ++i) {
          String name = Path.Combine(
            Path.GetDirectoryName(target),
            Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(target) + String.Format("(copy{0})", i) +
            Path.GetExtension(target));

          if (!File.Exists(name)) {
            File.Copy(source, name);

            break;
          }
        }
    }

...

  MoveCopy(filename, temp_file);
```

Comment: @juharr: Thank you! I really should have added `++i`.

Answer (score 4):

You can do it by checking for existing files, and generating new names for the destination, til it's not occupied, like this:

```
public static IEnumerable<string> FallbackPaths(string path)
{
    yield return path;

    var dir = Path.GetDirectoryName(path);
    var file = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(path);
    var ext = Path.GetExtension(path);

    yield return Path.Combine(dir, file + " - Copy" + ext);
    for (var i = 2; ; i++)
    {
        yield return Path.Combine(dir, file + " - Copy " + i + ext);
    }
}
public static void SafeCopy(string src, string dest)
{
    foreach (var path in FallbackPaths(dest))
    {
        if (!File.Exists(path))
        {
            File.Copy(src, path);
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Note that this function *can* give you `IOException` (for file already exists reason), if files with the same name are written concurrently.

Answer (score 3):

Use `File.Exists` method to check if file exist.

To rename file you can try to create loop more to check if `copy(1)` exist

Answer (score 0):

```
(File.Exists(fileName) ? "File exists." : "File does not exist.")
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what I did:

```
int p = 0;
while (File.Exists(temp_file))
{
    temp_file = Path.GetTempPath() + @"temp_presentation" + p.ToString() + ".pptx";
    p++;
}
File.Copy(filename, temp_file);
```